# Using FileVault and online backup on OS X

Tags: mac, backup, dropbox, filevault, carbonite

I use Carbonite for offsite backup, and am considering turing on FileVault on my Mac.  If I do so, what will happen to my Carbonite backup?  Will Carbonite have to redo the entire backup?  Does Carbonite even work if FileVault is enabled?

Also, how does FileVault play with other services like Dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

According to their forum, DropBox plays like a feisty five-year-old in a sandbox, i.e. not so well:

> http://wiki.dropbox.com/KnownIssues
>
> OSX
>
> Dropbox doesn't play well with
>   FileVault: Spotlight won't find files
>   in your FileVault locker including
>   your Dropbox, if it's in the locker.
>
> Solution: Move your Dropbox files
>   outside of FileVault. They won't be
>   encrypted (and you can't move them
>   back in), but it's a temporary fix.
>
> Alternative solution: You can teach
>   Spotlight to index all files in your
>   locker by adding your home folder to
>   the list of files Spotlight should be
>   prevented to index and subsequently
>   removing it again. You can find the
>   list under "Privacy" in the Sportlight
>   settings in System Preferences. Once
>   you added and removed the folder
>   again, Spotlight should start
>   indexing.
>
> Dropbox doesn't sync until restarted
>   for some users: No solution yet.
>
> Blockquote